# Getting current cursor pos within notepad++ plugin

Tags: c++, notepad++

I am trying to get line number at which  cursor is located. However I did not find straightforward method to just get the line. Instead i am trying to get current position then translate it into line using `SCI_LINEFROMPOSITION`.

```
::SendMessage(nppData._nppHandle,SCI_GETCURRENTPOS,0,(LPARAM)&first);
::SendMessage(nppData._scintillaMainHandle,SCI_GETCURRENTPOS,0,(LPARAM)&second);
::SendMessage(nppData._scintillaSecondHandle,SCI_GETCURRENTPOS,0,(LPARAM)&third);
```

Every of these calls does not change value of last parameter. Unfortunately I did not find examples for `SCI_GETCURRENTPOS`. I am able to insert text into file so I can check out the values this way:

```
std::wstringstream wss;
wss << "First value read" << first << std::endl;
wss << "Second value read" << second << std::endl;
wss << "Third value read" << third << std::endl;
insertTextIntoCurrentFile(wss.str().c_str());
```

How should I get current line? Which is the expected `HWND` to be send for `SendMessage` in this case?

Comment: Probably best to search/ask in the Notepad++ forum topic for plugin development: http://sourceforge.net/p/notepad-plus/discussion/482781/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this by searching notepad-plus discussion.
The answer was to read returned value from `SendMessage`.

to get Scintilla `HWND`:

```
int currentEdit;
::SendMessage(nppData._nppHandle, NPPM_GETCURRENTSCINTILLA, 0, (LPARAM)&currentEdit);
HWND curScint = (currentEdit == 0 ) ?
nppData._scintillaMainHandle:nppData._scintillaSecondHandle;
```

to get current cursor positions:

```
int cursorPosition = ::SendMessage(curScint,SCI_GETCURRENTPOS,0,0);
```

Answer (score 3):

The following answer is a clarified version of a combination of your initial question and your own answer (which is what led me to find this full solution).

```
// Position of the cursor in the entire buffer
int cursorPosition = ::SendMessage(nppData._scintillaMainHandle, SCI_GETCURRENTPOS, 0, 0);

// Line position of the cursor in the editor
int currentLine = ::SendMessage(nppData._nppHandle, NPPM_GETCURRENTLINE, 0, 0);

// Column position of the cursor in the editor
int currentColumn = ::SendMessage(nppData._nppHandle, NPPM_GETCURRENTCOLUMN, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way without calling `SendMessage()`, just by using [methods from standard Scintilla API](https://www.scintilla.org/ScintillaDoc.html) – pseudocode follows:

```
currentLineNumber = editor.SCI_LINEFROMPOSITION(editor.SCI_GETCURRENTPOS())
```

This is useful to keep the code at higher level or for scripting in other languages (like in N++ Python Script plugin) where it is easy to call documented API but the `SendMessage()` way might be more difficult. (Tested - it works.)